# np.linalg.norm ord=2 not giving Euclidean norm

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to compute the Euclidean distance between two matricies which I would expect to be given by the square root of the element-wise sum of squared differences.

This *seems* to me to be exactly the calculation computed by numpy's [linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) function, however it doesn't appear to match my expected result.

For example this code returns different values (`5.385` vs `5.339`)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(6).reshape(2, 3)
b = np.array([[1,2,3], [-1,1,4]])

print(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a-b))))
print(np.linalg.norm(a-b, 2))
```

Have I misinterpreted the [linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) function? Why are the two above calculation methodologies not returning the same value?

Comment: You are normalizing over only one axis (the 2nd axis), try ```np.linalg.norm(a-b, None)``` and you should see it equal to ```5.385```

Comment: @Kevin, thank you but the default is already None and explictly adding None still gives the same result as without.

Comment: hmm strange, for me both prints are exactly equal with ```print(np.linalg.norm(a-b, None))```. Running numpy version 1.20.0.

Comment: Try this otherwise: ```np.linalg.norm(a-b, axis=None)```. The ```axis=None``` is default keyword for ```np.sum```.

Comment: @Kevin, apologies, I miss read your comment. I thought you meant `axis=None`. Indeed if `ord=None` rather than `ord=2` they do return the same value. But then how is the `ord=None` different from `ord=2`?

Comment: No worries, take a look at my previous comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I can see in the DocString of `np.linalg.norm`, it looks like for arrays with dim>2, it takes the largest singular value for `ord=2`, meaning `np.linalg.norm(a, ord=2)` is the same as `np.linalg.svd(a)[1].max()`. So in your case that's gonna be:

```
print(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(a-b))))
print(np.linalg.norm(a-b, 2))
print(np.linalg.svd(a-b)[1].max())
```

And this will return `5.385`, `5.339`, `5.339`.

The mathematical formulation is given [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), where the distinction is made between 2-norm (which is `ord=2`) and Frobenius norm (`ord=None`).

Comment: Thank you, I had incorrectly assumed that the 2-norm and Frobenius norm were defined the same.

Comment: Actually me too. I'm glad you asked this question because I also learned something.